# get average per month in a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DATENAME(month, CurrentDate) AS MonthName, 
    DATENAME(year, CurrentDate) AS Year, 
    MONTH(CurrentDate) AS MonthNumber
FROM
    dbo.Prices
GROUP BY 
    CurrentDate, DATENAME(month, CurrentDate), 
    DATENAME(year, CurrentDate), MONTH(CurrentDate)
```

When I run this I get one row as result which is expected

The table has two columns `CurrentDate` and `CurrentPrice`, but when I run this query...

```
SELECT        
    DATENAME(month, CurrentDate) AS MonthName, 
    DATENAME(year, CurrentDate) AS Year, 
    MONTH(CurrentDate) AS MonthNumber, 
    CAST(AVG(CurrentPrice) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Price
FROM
    dbo.Prices
GROUP BY 
    CurrentDate, DATENAME(month, CurrentDate), 
    DATENAME(year, CurrentDate), MONTH(CurrentDate)
```

I don't get one row with a average value of each month, instead I get a average value for each date. How can I change the query so I get one average value per month?

Data structure is like this....

```
CurrentDate                 CurrentPrice
-----------------------------------------
2022-09-06 00:00:00.000     59.81
2022-09-06 01:00:00.000     63.83
```

Comment: Don't `group by CurrentDate`.

Comment: In most cases you do not need a to use a DISTINCT with a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Treuss stated get rid of the current date the grain will break your aggregation

```
SELECT        
    DATENAME(month, CurrentDate) AS MonthName, 
    DATENAME(year, CurrentDate) AS Year, 
    MONTH(CurrentDate) AS MonthNumber, 
    CAST(AVG(CurrentPrice) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Price
FROM
    dbo.Prices
GROUP BY 
 --   CurrentDate  --Omit this.  
 , DATENAME(month, CurrentDate)
 ,  DATENAME(year, CurrentDate)
 , MONTH(CurrentDate)
```